# How to add the API key to use Google Cloud TTS?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a simple testing app for Cloud TTS. The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java) does not seem to provide any specific information about Android, and the closest thing was Java.

I created a default app and then added the library like this,

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:0.82.0-beta'
```

which caused a weird build error, so I added this after reading an existing StackOverflow question

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
}
```

Now it compiles, but of course it caused a runtime exception saying that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must be defined. But how to do that with Android? The documentation page only had instructions for Windows/Linux/macOS.

---

In case someone sees this question in the future, I think I solved this by doing what [this page](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/texttospeech/v1beta1/TextToSpeechClient.html) does. I copied the `credential.json` to the `raw` directory, and did the following thing before calling the API.

```
    val cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credentials));
    val buil = TextToSpeechSettings.newBuilder();
    buil.credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(cred);
    val sett = buil.build();

    // Instantiates a client
    TextToSpeechClient.create(sett).use { textToSpeechClient ->
```

Comment: Daaamn, finally something that actually works, just in time, as I was about to lose the rest of my hope. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/changemyminds/Google-Cloud-TTS-Android) for Google Cloud TTS.

You can read the [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3400) about Google Cloud TTS Github Issues.

Google Cloud TTS does not currently support the android.

You can use Restful API to get audio Base64 encoding and use MediaPlayer library to play audio.

Answer (score -1):

1. Copy your credential information which contains `type`, `private_key`
2. Write content of Step 1 into `credential.json` file.
3. Copy file of Step 2 into `/res/raw` folder. (If it's not working, put file into `assets` folder.)

Or, you can parse environment variables and write into `credential.json` file.

Below code comes from [GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/nl/Language/app/build.gradle#L79).

```
task copySecretKey(type: Copy) {
    def File secretKey = file "$System.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
    from secretKey.getParent()
    include secretKey.getName()
    into 'src/main/res/raw'
    rename secretKey.getName(), "credential.json"
}
```

Comment: I got the json file (which included the two values as well as others) from the Console, and added the code as well as `preBuild.dependsOn(copySecretKey)`, but I got the same error message of `The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.`

Comment: Can I create crediental.json directly in the raw and assets folders without using the code above? In my experience, I remember that I put it in assets.

Comment: At first I could not understand that the code does but I began to think that it just copies the JSON file from the environment path to the `raw` directory. But as I have wrote, I already had copied the downloaded JSON to `raw`. So, I have tried to removing the task code, but I still got the same error. This is my first time using Cloud TTS, but I used GCM before and I think I once have added the JSON credential file to an app. But now I cannot remember how I did it, or I am not sure if Cloud TTS works the same way. I think I need to search the web some more. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think I solved this. Now I have another problem though. I will add the solution to the end of the question.